# Eliminar Valores duplicados (pero no exactos) Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Utilizando Google App Script quiero borrar (no eliminar) los valores de las celdas que tengan una palabra que yo elija.

Por ejemplo lucas se repite 2 veces, quiero borrar las celdas que contengan el valor "lucas" de toda la columna A, pero manteniendo el formato y todo.

No quiero eliminar las filas que contengan el valor "lucas" ni nada, solo borrar las celdas que contengan el valor "lucas" de  toda la columna A. He encontrado lo básico de borrar filas repetidas y cosas así, pero no encuentro específicamente como borrar las celdas que contengan  valores repetidos (SOLO ESOS VALORES) manteniendo el formato. Allí esta  mi código y un screeshoot del error que obtengo.

Si utilizo la funcion UNIQUE hay dos problemas : El primero es que el valor de la celda tiene que ser exacto (solo decir lucas, mas nada) y el segundo problema es que elimina esa celda ( y no la quiero eliminar , solo borrar)

```
function prueba(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var last = sheet.getLastRow();
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,last);
var value = range.getValues();
for (var i=0; i < last+1 ; i++){
  if (value[1][i] == 'lucas'){
    sheet.getRange(i,1).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Codigo de App Script]

Les agradeceria si no seria molestia poder ayudarme. He intentado de todo.

Answer (score 1):

### ML,NLL (TL,DR)

[Asómate a la hoja funcionando](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pt3pcNbqJA-IwLDubzQRm0gQ9Ttgouuto6CZ4VqDOVE/edit?usp=sharing): puedes descargarla para examinar el código. Hay un menú extra en para ejecutar el código. que está aqui abajo también

##### Ahora si, el  detalle:

Hay varios problemas en tu codigo.

El primero es que la condición que estas probando en los datos, nunca va a cumplirse, al menos no con esos datos. (estas buscando la cadena `lucas` sin embargo, los candidatos son en un caso `lucas miguel` y `lucas rincon`) Aun que el programa estuviera correcto, no verías los resultados que esperas.
Ajusté los datos de prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

Ahora si, el problema que tienes es que estas iterando sobre un array inexistente.

`sheet.getLastRow()` te regresa el último renglón de la hoja de cálculo (A999) no el último renglon de tu rango de datos.

por otro lado estás iterando un array basado en 0 sobre un rango basado en 1 (la referencia de renglón numérica) introduciendo un clasico *error por uno*

finalmente en cada vuelta del bucle llamarías al API para borrar el dato, lo que en AppScript es muy caro, recuerda que tu script completo debe terminar en [menos de 6 minutos](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=es). Cuando llamaste `var value = range.getValues();` tienes una instancia estándar de un array javascript, con tódos sus métodos y propiedades que podemos aprovechar.

ahora, el problema central que tienes es que range.getValues() **siempre** regresa un array bidimensional, [la documentación lo indica](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=es#getvalues) como `Object[][]` es un poco contraintuitivo, yo tardé en entenderlo bien. basicamente tienes para tus dos columnas y 6 renglones algo asi:

```
values =[[A1,B1], [A2, B2], ... [A6,B6]]
```

para que tu código funcione, aprovecha que ya tienes el array de datos en la variable values y puedes usar sus propiedades para limitar las iteraciones sin llamar a la hoja de calculo (esta es una de las mejores practicas)

Otras mejoras que puedes hacer son:

- limita los permisos del script con el comentario mágico `/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */` en el prrmer renglón
- obtén el rango de datos usando `data = Spreadsheet.getDataRange();` asi los límites de iteración son `data.length` y `data[0].length` para renglones y columnas respectivamente
- Aún mejor, usa `Spreadsheet.getSelection().getActiveRange()` para obtener los datos que seleccionaste interactivamente en la hoja de cálculo
- Procura encadenar todos los métodos que puedas encadenar, como aqui arriba, en lugar de hacer 3 llamadas y 3 asignaciones, a variables solo haces  una sola.
- Trabaja todo el tiempo que puedas con los objetos nativos de Javascript, en lugar de llamar a la hoja de calculo para cada celda. al final los arrays los descargas a la hoja con  `Range.setValues()`

Esto hará una gran diferencia, aquí está el tiempo de ejecución usando tu codigo corregido, usando una versión que hace las operaciones en JS y al final descarga con `Range.setValues()` y una version que usa agresivamente las optimizaciones de JS6 disponibles en AppScript (notación de flecha, métodos nuevos de arrays, iteradores):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me faltó mencionar que usando los métodos de String.protoype en javascript puedes encontrar coincidencias parciales, lo que es mejor que el operador lógico de igualdad para encontrarlas, usando expresiones regulares (regex) por ejemplo /.+Lucas.+/ Coincide solo con Lucas usando inicial mayúscula. La documentación se soporte para regex se apps script es la de la librería re2 de Google.

Finalmente, aquí está tu código corregido para usar el array bidimensional y la version optimizada:

#### Tu codigo con array bidimensional

```js
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */
// usa menos permisos!! =)

function prueba(){
  console.time('corregido')
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()        //  en lugar de .getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();      // en lugar de sheet.getRange(1,1,last);
  var renglones = range.getNumRows()     // quieres el ultimo renglon, del rango no de la hojasheet.getLastRow();
  var columnas = range.getNumColumns()   // ahora tenemos las dimensiones del rango 
  var celda = range.getValues();         // esto es un array de arrays de Renglones x Columnas
                                         // en este caso es 6x2 [[A1,A2][B1,B2]...[F1,F2]]

  // iteramos sobre los renglones, cada bucle da un array 1xN [Col1,Col2...ColN]
  for (var renglon=0; renglon <= renglones - 1 ; renglon++){
    // iteramos sobre las columnas, obteniendo valores escalares Col1, Col2...ColN
    for (var columna=0; columna <= columnas - 1 ; columna++){
      if (celda[renglon][columna].match('lucas')){
        // solo cambia el valor si hay un match, !
        celda[renglon][columna].replace(celda[renglon][columna],"")
        // aqui el valor es un string y podemus usar sus metodos
      }
    }
  }
  // ya que tenemos un array con los nuevos valores, solo debemos descargarlos 
  // en el rango original, asi se hace una sola llamada al API mucho mas eficiente
  range.setValues(celda)
  console.timeEnd('corregido')
```

#### Verison optimizada

```js
function limpiadorRecursivoB(rng){
  if (!(rng instanceof Array)) {         // si la selccion es escalar, conviertela 
    return limpiadorRecursivoB([[rng]])  // en un array anidado de 1x1
  }                   
  var nArr=[]                   
  var cell =""
  for ( row of rng ) {
    nRow = []
    for ( col of row ){
      if (col.match(/^lucas$/)){ // aqui puedes jugar con el regex para eliminar
        nRow.push("")            // coincidencias parciales. v.gr /^lucas.+/ coincide con
      } else {                   // celdas que EMPIEZAN con lucas, otros ejemplos:
                         // /.+lucas$/  celdas que terminan en lucas
        nRow.push(col)           // /lucas/i    celdas que contienen 'lucas' enncualquier
      }                          //             posicion insensible a mayusculas
      nArr.push(nRow)            // /.uca./     cualquier letra alrededor de 'uca'
    }                            //             coincide con tucan rucas mucaz etc
  }                              // el soporte de regex es la libreria re2 de google
return nArr;                     // solo googlea 're2 -site:github.com'
}

function optimizado(){
  console.time('optimizado');
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // declara constante
  var rango = ss.getActiveSheet()   //  en lugar de .getSheets()[0];
                .getSelection()     // usa la seleccion, para ser flexible 
                .getActiveRange();  // encadenando los metodos solo haces una llamada!!
  var valores = rango.getValues(); // valores es un array JS regular!                                    
  //const nuevosValores = limpiadorRecursivoA(valores) // todas las operaciones las hacemos en arrays
  const nuevosValores = limpiadorRecursivoB(valores) // todas las operaciones las hacemos en arrays
  rango.setValues(nuevosValores);  // el array final lo regresamos a la hoja
  console.timeEnd('optimizado');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente el problem es que en la expresion condicional del bucle (for) está `last + 1`, siendo `last` el número de fila de la última fila. Deberías ser `last - 1` porque estás inicializando el iterador `i` en `0`.

Comment: Como estas Ruben. Ya no presenta el error, pero no borra nada todavia. De todas maneras ya tengo una solucion, pero con una tecnica diferente. Aunque en verdad quisiera saber cual es el problema para aprender . No se si  poner la solucion aqui ( es muy diferente o abrir una nueva pregunta. Porque en verdad tengo un problema con la nueva solucion.

Comment: Hola @NIN . Puedes usar los comentarios para solicitar clarificación de una respuesta pero si se trata de hacer una pregunta sobre el código modificado, o de una solución diferente con algúna problema, en el primer caso sería una pregunta de seguimiento, en el segundo se trata de una pregunta diferente. En ambos casos  deben hacerse publicando una nueva pregunta.